# Admob real ads are not showing

Tags: android, admob

I am getting this error but when I put test ads they work fine but original are not working please help me out in this.
Error - W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

Answer (score 0):

this is said ,as per google support

***If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request. This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the new ID starts returning ads***

Comment: yes my account is almost 2 months ago and almost 500k ad request has been done but no ads is not showing

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

1. Add your payment information on main page of admob site, if you haven't already done this.
2. You have to publish game on google play at least to internal test to see ads, for my case there was the message when I'm installing game on phone "Unknown developer".

For more information add your code to the issue.